# How to get all articles that they dont have priority?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

With this i get an array of articles :

```
 $unsortedArticles = $this->article->getAllCurentTranslation($language);
```

I have this relationship between article and priority:

```
public function priority()
    {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Models\HomepagePriority','article_id','id');
    }
```

So how can i now return an array of articles but just articles that they dont have priority??

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`doesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence). Something like:

```
$articlesWithoutPriority = Aricle::doesntHave('priority')->get();
```

Solution by @Gerard Reches for your case (supposing that `getAllCurentTranslation($language)` method uses `->get()` at the end):

```
$unsortedArticles = $this->article()
                         ->doesntHave('priority')
                         ->getAllCurentTranslation($language);
```

Comment: but how can i use it in this  $unsortedArticles = $this->article->getAllCurentTranslation($language); ?